# Controlling Webots simulation step

Tags: webots

Is it possible to calculate the Webots simulation step programatically, i.e. each time one module finishes its planing than the Webots should calculate the next simulation step dependent upon the output of the module.

I have checked the Supervisor mode but it does not seems to have some control over the simulation run apart from setting the simulation mode.

#### Edit 1:

How to "execute one simulation step (ctrl + 1 in the Webots environment)" from the script after the planning completion of one other ROS node?

Answer (score 4):

In a Supervisor controller, you can also access to all the Robot API. Therefore, it's possible to get the global discrete time step constant (defined by [the WorldInfo.basicTimeStep field](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/worldinfo#worldinfo)) using the [wb_robot_get_basic_time_step()](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/robot#wb_robot_get_basic_time_step) function, and to get the simulated time in seconds using the [wb_robot_get_time()](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/robot#wb_robot_get_time) function.

The simulation basic time step is a constant which cannot be modified during the simulation. The simulation goes ahead when controllers (including supervisors) call the [wb_robot_step(int duration)](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/robot#wb_robot_step) function, and the hand will be given back to the controller after this "duration". During this period, one (or more if "duration" is strictly bigger than "WorldInfo.basicTimeStep")
simulation steps can be applied.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I meant to say how to execute one simulation step instead of calculation, I have edited the question can you please answer that as well.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I skipped your comment. I will answer it as a new answer.

Answer (score 2):

After your edition, here is a more specific answer. My previous answer remains correct but is more general.

When a controller is synchronized (the default case of the [Robot.synchronization](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/robot) field), Webots is waiting that the controller calls the [wb_robot_step(int duration)](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/robot#wb_robot_step) function to perform simulation steps.

So if you would like to perform a single step from a controller (like when pressing to `Ctrl + 1`, you simply need to call the [wb_robot_step(int duration)](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/robot#wb_robot_step) function once.

To illustrate this, the following controller performs one simulation step every 3 seconds:

```py
"""Perform one simulation step after some event."""

from controller import Robot
import time

robot = Robot()
timestep = int(robot.getBasicTimeStep())

while True:
    time.sleep(3)  # Wait 3 real seconds to simulate a blocking event.

    print 'Perform a simulation step.'
    robot.step(timestep)
```